# How to determine if the sequence $a_n = \frac{[(-1)^n+1](n+1)}{n}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm studying for a upcoming test about sequences. While solving some exercises I had trouble figuring out if this sequence converges or not.

$$a_n = \frac{[(-1)^n+1] \cdot (n+1)}{n}$$

May anyone teach me how to determinate if it converges or not?

Comment: $n$ odd: $a_n = 0$. $n$ even: $a_n \approx 2$

Comment: one way is to check if it is Cauchy

Comment: the sequence is always 0, 2, 0, 2... so it never converges

Comment: @user29418 No the sequence is $0,3,0,5/2,0,....$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $|a_{n+1} - a_n|\longrightarrow 2$